# Slow looper frame issue android

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-looper

Basically, from one day to another, without any change, the Android app is showing:

```
Slow Looper main: doFrame is 301ms late because of 69 msg, msg 1 took 311ms (late=52ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver)
```

How do I debug this error, is it from Android Studio? I tried Invalidate cache / restart and still the same...

Thank you.

EDIT:
I noticed is my device. On emulator runs exact as it ran before.